# Problem of analytic continuation in George Polya's Problems and Theorems in Analysis I

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\mathfrak{H}$ denote the half-strip
>
> $\text{Re} z>0, \quad-\pi<\text{Im} z<\pi$
>
> and $L$ the boundary of $\mathfrak{H}$ consisting of three straight
> pieces. We orient $L$ so that is on the right hand side of L.
>
> The integral $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{L} \frac{e^{e^{\zeta}}}{\zeta-z} d\zeta=E(z)$ defines a function $E(z)$ for points z on the left hand side
> of $L$.
>
> Show that $E(z)$ is an entire function which assumes real
> values for real z.”

[[Page 334,George Polya·Gabor Szego,Problems and Theorems in Analysis I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3lLN.png)]

This is one of the problems in Problems and Theorems in Analysis I(George Polya·Gabor Szego,page 135). The picture is the solution in the book.
I know how to prove that the integral in $E(z)$ is convergent for $z\notin L$ .But I don't understand how to prove $E(z)$ is holomorphic and how to extend $E(z)$ analytically over the entire plane.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Suggestion: What can you say about $E(z-2\pi i)$?